# Detect where JS was served from

Tags: javascript

I would like to detect if someone has made a local copy of my javascript library or is loading it from the canonical location.  I'm wondering if there's any way for a JS library to inspect where it was loaded from.

I don't know of any way to do this, so the best I can think of is to have the JS inspect all the `<script>` tags in the DOM to see if any point to the canonical location.  If not then I know the JS must have been loaded from somewhere else.

I'm wondering if there's a better solution though, preferably with the JS able to tell what URL it was loaded from.  Does such a mechanism exist?

Comment: `window.location.href`?

Comment: This sounds slightly ill-conceived. Are you trying to implement some kind of copy-protection?

Comment: @Amy — That tells you the URL of the HTML document, not the script element.

Comment: If he wants to detect if someone stole his code, he would check to see who is using the code, not where the code is hosted.

Comment: @Amy — They haven't said that is what they are trying to detect.

Comment: @Quentin I'm aware of that.  I'm also aware of what `window.location.href` does, thanks.

Comment: @meagar Not quite.  We've had a problem where customers make their own copy of our JS library and use that instead of the canonical one they should be using.  This causes version drift as we change things (we release an update about once a week), and has caused error spikes multiple times as the old JS suddenly breaks.  We're looking for a way to detect this in ways that don't involve sudden spikes in our error monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your code check it's own `<script>` element by accessing [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript). It holds a reference to the currently processed `<script>` element. Test the `src` attribute to see if is not set, or if it doesn't match your domain.

```
var scriptLocation = document.currentScript.src;
if(!scriptLocation || scriptLocation.indexOf("http://example.com") != 0){
  //inline script or loaded from some other site
}
```

Note though if you put the code in some async use (ie promise callback etc) it will not hold your code's script element.

Comment: a lot is async, but I can insert the code to check in the initial bootstrap.
I'll give this a try tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: In that case you could just save the reference in the bootstrap and then in you async code use that reference instead of directly using currentScript.